# Saving a record from php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to save some values from my query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT * FROM acceso WHERE usuario = '$user' AND contrasenia = '$pass'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)// mysqli_num_rows > 0
{       
    $fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)
    $_SESSION["id_usuario_cms"] = $fila ['idacces'];
    $_SESSION["usuario_cms"] = $fila ['user'];
    echo '<script>location.href = "admin/index.php"</script>';
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you do `session_start()` at the beginning of the script?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` you can't use that function with `mysqli_`.

Answer (score 2):

I see one potential problem and one obvious problem.

The potential is if you've started the session or not.

`session_start();` is required to be used inside all files using sessions; this isn't mentioned in your question. If it's not part of your file(s), add it.

The obvious being that, you're using a `mysql_` function being mixed in with the rest of your shown code, being `mysqli_`. Those different functions do not intermix with each other.

`mysql_fetch_assoc` needs to be its `mysqli_` equivalent, `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

You should be using `mysqli_fetch_array` for this though.

In order to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, it should be set in a `while` loop.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Example from the manual:

```
/* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }
```

If you wish to use `mysqli_fetch_array`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Example from the manual:

```
/* associative array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

Including `or die(mysqli_error($conex))` to `mysqli_query()`.

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: I have not said another thing, we mention the same thing, I just dont released mysqli, you are not honest

Comment: @budamivardi what are you talking about? Your downvote is uncalled for by the way; **remove it.** You're the one that is wrong.

Comment: Its warn me "You last voted on this answer 31 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited"; you need edit answer little

Comment: @budamivardi so, what are you waiting for?

Comment: @budamivardi did you not remove your downvote as you said you would? My answer still shows a -1

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **mysqli_fetch_array($query)** also **session_start()**

```
$query = mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT * FROM acceso WHERE usuario = '$user' AND contrasenia = '$pass'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)// mysqli_num_rows > 0
    {       
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query)
        $_SESSION["id_usuario_cms"] = $fila ['idacces'];
        $_SESSION["usuario_cms"] = $fila ['user'];
        echo '<script>location.href = "admin/index.php"</script>';
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. *You have to use mysql_fetch_array* totally wrong. That's the pot calling the kettle black.

Comment: Now you changed it to `mysqli_` it's about time you realized the error. Now remove your downvote.

Comment: So did you remove the downvote; you haven't answered me. My answer still has a -1